# Image not displayed on Angular Drag and Drop Component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```js
export class CountriesPage {
  todo = [
    'url: https://www.countryflags.io/gb/shiny/64.png',
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Countries</h2>

  <div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="todo"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="doneList" class="list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="list-item" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
  <img [src]='list.url'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am about to create a country App where the user can drag the country he has already visited and drop it on the done array. I am using the Angular DragandDrop Component for that purpose and I need to know how to implement in the todo array the following country flag correctly

console.log says: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

Your img tag it's misplaced

```
<div class="list-item" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>
  <img [src]="list.url" />
</div>
```

And the array "todo" must be an array of objects (key: value)

```
todo = [
    {url: 'https://www.countryflags.io/gb/shiny/64.png'}
]
```

Here's a example in stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knvetq

Hope i helped.

Comment: You are the best. Thanks a lot, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud replace list by item, try this

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Countries</h2>

  <div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="todo"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="doneList" class="list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="list-item" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
  <img [src]='item.url'/>
  </div>
</div>
```